# how to change vscode tabs order with keyboard shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

how can I change order of tabs in VSCode without leaving the keyboard ?

I mean like this :

[image]

to this :

[image]

I changed here the order of tabs, usually I can do it with mouse by dragging, but I want to know if there is any way to do it with keyboard only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You have the commands `workbench.action.moveEditorLeftInGroup` and `workbench.action.moveEditorRightInGroup` (for example on Windows they're by default bound to `Ctrl+Shift+PageUp` and `Ctrl+Shift+PageDown` respectively).

Comment: On macOS, these shorts default to `⌘ K + ⌘ ⇧ →` & `⌘ K + ⌘ ⇧ ←`